# How to set auto-width for text rows?

Tags: python, parsing, text, output

I have the python-function:

```
def myFunction(inputList):
    outputList = ['Path      |      Type      |      Size']
    for item in inputList:
        outputList.append(item + '      |      ' + parseFileType(item) + '      |      ' + parseFileSize(item))
    return outputList
```

And I have following output from this function:

```
Path      |      Type      |      Size
/etc/acpi       |      directory      |      16 Kb.
/etc/adduser.conf       |      ASCII text      |      4,0 Kb.
/bin/df |      ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=8b0d9cd8d2256a94b9ea7e2248b6d8721cff588d, stripped      |      84 Kb.
```

How can I make auto-width for text output from this function, for it looks like:

```
Path                |      Type           |      Size
/etc/acpi           |      directory      |      16 Kb.
/etc/adduser.conf   |      ASCII text     |      4,0 Kb.
...
```

Comment: Well, you have to DO it.  You'd have to run through the list once to figure out how wide each column has to be, then run through it again padding each column with spaces to fill that width.  It's up to you to decide how to handle very long lines, like your third entry.

Comment: Hello, Tim, thanks you, maybe somewhere available some algorithms to standardize my output?

Comment: No, there is no standard for this kind of thing.  Only YOU know what you want the output to look like.  Some people would print HTML and let a browser make it pretty.

Comment: I think I should use something like "columnar" module, but it requires Python v. 3.7.x, but I shoud code for Python v. 2.x or v. 3.5.x.

Comment: There are only two source files in that package.  It wouldn't take you long to remove the type annotations and convert the `f"..."` strings to regular string formatting.

Comment: @TimRoberts, Thanks you, about convertation the strings from ```f""``` to ```""``` format I understand; but about removing the type annotations - not completely understand you, can you show me example, please?

Comment: The code has lines like `data: Sequence[Sequence[Any]],` and `head: int = 0`.  Those "colon" clauses are type hints, saying that `head` is supposed to be an integer.  This was added in Python 3.5.  They are used by syntax checkers, and do not affect the code in any way.  You'll need to remove those, to say `data,` and `head = 0`.  Same with function returns:  `...) -> str:` says the func returns a string.  Change that to `...):`.

Answer (score -1):

> In Python, strings have a built-in method named ljust. The method lets you pad a string with characters up to a certain length.

> The ljust method means "left-justify"; this makes sense because your string will be to the left after adjustment up to the specified length.

You can try this to make sure each string will have the same length, that would guarantee your columns to look like you want them to look like.

Comment: And how do you expect him to do that?

Comment: How? By iterating over every item so he can possibly adjust the length of each string to e.g. 25.. or whatever length he needs? Every string would be the same length (will have spaces at the end) so all his columns will look nice and tidy. It was just an idea, hopefully, a useful one.